# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non object

Tags: php, mysqli

I've got this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/login.php on line 8

The line is this:

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user='$user' and password='$pw'");
```

This is login.php:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$pw = md5($pass); 
include_once('connect.php');

function check_login($user,$pw,&$result){
    $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user='$user' and password='$pw'");
    $cont = 0;
    while($row = $res->fetch_object()){
        $cont++;
        $result = $row;
    }
    if($cont == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
  if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    if(check_login($user,$pw,$result) == 1){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $result->id_user;
        header("location:index.php?var=ok");
    }
    else{
        header('location:index.php?var=log');
    }
  }
}
```

And the code of connect.php :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'cms' );
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
   die('Error de Conexión (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
        . $mysqli->connect_error);
 }
```

What could be the problem? Problems connecting the database?

Comment: `$mysqli` is not in your function scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is most likely a [scoping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue. This means that the variable `$mysqli` that you define in your included file is outside of the `check_login` function's scope (i.e. is not known inside this function).

You could try to get the `$mysqli` variable from global scope with

```
function check_login($user,$pw,&$result){
    global $mysqli;
    $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user='$user' and password='$pw'");
    // ...
```

**Edit**: Oh, and you should also mind the SQL injection vulnerabiliy in your code. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent this issue (or at least escape your input variables with a function like [`mysqli::real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)).

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you and all for the quick response and helping me.

Edit: I know my code is vulnerable on SQL Injections. I'm learning PHP so step by step :)

Answer (score 3):

```
function check_login($user,$pw,&$result){
    global $mysqli;
    $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user='$user' and password='$pw'");
    $cont = 0;
    while($row = $re[...]
```

Mind the "global". This puts the var in the scope of your method.
This is a quick and dirty solution, but will work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your $mysqli variable is not being set properly within the scope of your code thats executing the query.  Can you confirm that $mysqli is indeed a mysqli object and not, say, set to null?

You can check this by doing: `echo print_r($mysqli);` right before you call the ->query method in your code.

If it is not set properly, track the variable backward in your code until you see why

Answer (score 2):

variable $mysqli in function check_login is out of scope (it is declare outside the function) so it is null.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function connectDB($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName) {
            global $con;
            $con = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName) or die ("Error occured");
            return $con;
```

and then pass `$con` in all the functions that you define or run wherever.